# How to Include .h files from static library into .app build in Objective C and Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I built a static libxyz.a in one xcode project and am trying to include it in a separate app project abc.xcodeproj. I also put the public .h files in Build Phase->Copy Files in this library project, according to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH2-SW1

I included libxyz.a in Build Phase->Link Binary With Libraries of all the dependent frameworks.

However when I tried to build the abc.app target, I got error messages that the public .h files from the libxyz.a proejct could not be found.

I tried several things but could not fix the problem.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add those header file to your project also. When you create a static library, it'll give you a include folder. You need to include all the stuffs available in that folder when you are adding that static library to other projects

Comment: Check your Header Search Path under Build Settings of your Target.